# How can I append json data in memory to the end of a new-line delimited json file without reading the file into memory in Rust?

Tags: json, rust

If I have a new-line delimited `json` file that looks something like this:

```json
{"name":"butthead"}
{"name":"second-butthead"}
{"name":"third-butthead"}
```

And I have data loaded into memory that looks like this:

```json
{"name":"fourth-butthead"}
```

How can I append the data I have in memory to the end of the json file without reading the json file into memory, using Rust, so that the json file ends like this:

```json
{"name":"butthead"}
{"name":"second-butthead"}
{"name":"third-butthead"}
{"name":"fourth-butthead"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best variant for appending a new line in a text file?](/q/30684624/2189130)

Comment: I believe it does! Thank you @kmdreko